# how to toggled mini cart to Woocommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I want that add mini cart for my site. How to hide and show dropdown for mini cart when clicked button cart?

I use of JS for slidetoggle but not working. Please aid me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".buttonreq").click(function() {
    $(".widget_shopping_cart_content").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn bg-white buttonreq">
  <a class="text-dark" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'نمایش سبد خرید' );  ?>"> 
    <number><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count( ); ?></number>
    <span calss="cart">سبد خرید <i class="demo-icon text-danger icon-cart">&#xe817;</i></span>
  </a>   
</button>
<div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">
  <?php woocommerce_mini_cart(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide `widget_shopping_cart_content` check below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".buttonreq").click(function() {
    $(".widget_shopping_cart_content").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.widget_shopping_cart_content{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn bg-white buttonreq">
    <?php _e( 'نمایش سبد خرید' );  ?>
    <number>(5)</number>
    <span calss="cart">سبد خرید <i class="demo-icon text-danger icon-cart">&#xe817;</i></span>
</button>
<div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">
  <?php woocommerce_mini_cart(); ?> mini cart
</div>
```